# Using same cables for PSU

Tags: power-supply

Im looking to upgrade my current RM650x power supply to a RM850x. Is it possible to use the same cables from the old psu with the new psu even thou it just a change of watts or would I need to gut the old cables out and replace them with the new ones?

Want to figure this out before i plan out the change.

Current PSU: Corsair RM650x Full-Modular

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Please edit your question (gray to the bottom left of the question text) to indicate the whole make/model.  Presumably Corsair, but I don't want to assume.

Comment: My answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1385201/707676) might be relevant.. Short story - it's risky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power Supply cables are not generally interchangeable.
Almost all modular power supplies state this fact in the manual:
Do not use any cable not designed for this power supply.

Both the
[RM650x](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Power/Plug-Type/RMx-Series/p/CP-9020178-NA)
and the
[RM850x](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Power/Plug-Type/RMx-Series/p/CP-9020093-NA)
are modular PSUs that come each with its own full cable set, which you should use
(the RM850x has 3 more of them for some reason).

Don't take any chances and study well the documentation.
If in doubt, better ask a professional before frying up some devices.

Comment: I went ahead and just gutted out the old cables and used the new ones that came with the 850x. Even thou they were modular, I didn't want to risk it if something happened. Also the 3 extra cables I have no idea either.

Answer (score 0):

The external power cable (PSU outer side to wall) is usually interchangeable for personal computers.  PSUs are generally sold with a fresh power cable with a NEMA 5-15P plug, but it's usually fine to use the old one.  Some cables have a maximum power rating printed on the outside.

The internal cabling (PSU inner side to motherboard or other components) is not guaranteed to be interchangeable.  A PSU is either modular or non-modular.  Modular means that there are plugs on the inner side of the PSU, and those will vary by model.  Non-modular or cabled means that the cables come straight out of the inner side of the PSU, so those cannot be removed.  http://www.buildcomputers.net/modular-psu.html

It's good to ask on tech sites like SuperUser, but the vendor is the most reliable resource for sure answers.  I suggest going to Corsair with this question, and adding your own Answer below afterward.