# Repair hard drive short circuited by miss pinned PSU?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, hardware-failure

The RAID volume in my Synology NAS crashed and their advice was to plug the drives into another computer to attempt recovery. The volume crashed, but both drives were healthy and some of the data was available when I shut the NAS down.

My current desktop computer doesn't normally hold SATA hard drives but I found a six pin SATA power cable from an older PSU that fit into the SATA slot on my PSU. I connected the drives to the power cable, and the cable to the PSU, and booted to an Ubuntu live usb. The drives never showed up in `lsblk`. Booted into windows and the drives didn't show up there either. Eventually I noticed the smell of fried electronics and shut down the computer. I returned the drives to the NAS and they are not detected.

1. Did I fry the drives? Or were they just failing and moving them was enough to kill them?
2. Could I easily and cheaply recover the drives? Maybe replace a fuse or the chip? The data is not worth more than the drives.
3. Is it normal for modular PSU cables not to be swappable? How would I test if a SATA cable can be used with a PSU? [Yes, PSU's have different pin outs for the same six pin connectors](https://superuser.com/questions/1385197/do-ssds-die-when-plugged-in-psu-with-different-sata-cable/1385201#1385201)

[Pictures of drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Catr9.jpg). One drive is clearly scorched, I couldn't find any damage on the other.

Comment: 1. yes 2. no 3. yes

Comment: The only way to recover the data if you've fried the drive's PCB is to send it to a data recovery clean room for platter removal and the RAW data to be copied onto another drive since HDD PCB's aren't hot swappable between the same models. Clean room data recovery services often run a couple hundred per drive due to the clean room.

Comment: I've had success in the past desoldering the serial memory chip from the drive's controller board and soldering it onto a donor controller board. Of course this won't work if the serial memory chip was one of the components that died.

Comment: Can you explain (or link an explanation) why you can't swap hdd control pcbs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have lost the data and the drives (per your relatively low value of the data).

It sounds like you released the "magic smoke" from the drives.  More accurately it sounds like you have blown the capacitors and possibly other components on the power regulation/input of the drives - which is what you are smelling.  I'm not saying data recovery is not possible - it very likely is - just that it will be more expensive then the value you put on the data.

So -

1. Yes, you fried your drives.
2. No - you would need an expert to rebuild/bypass the power input.
3. Modular PSU cables are typically swap-able. Tour approach was reasonable. Sucks it did not work.

Comment: "Modular PSU cables are typically swap-able. Tour approach was reasonable. Sucks it did not work." sorry but no, there is no standard for the PSU end of "modular" cables.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Did I fry the drives? Or were they just failing and moving them was enough to kill them?

You destroyed something.

> 2. Could I easily and cheaply recover the drives? Maybe replace a fuse or the chip? The data is not worth more than the drives.

If you just changed polarity it might be sufficient to replace a certain diode. If, however, the dammage extends beyond the power regulator(s) a certain chip which carries drive-specific information might be broken. In this case a simple PCB swap (no clean room required) would not be possible.

> 3. Is it normal for modular PSU cables not to be swappable?

Only the settings where the cable ends are defined as far as I know.

> How would I test if a SATA cable can be used with a PSU? Yes, PSU's have different pin outs for the same six pin connectors

You would measure voltage and polarity.

**Conclusion:**

You should have provided a picture of your PCB to enable the possibility to visual estimate the extent of the dammage done.

You failed by not connecting your drive to a well-defined environment such as a docking station. Instead you were betting on a correct pin assignment.
Question 3 outlines that you are still willing to work with unsafe setups.
Your question concerning "testing" of the cables suggests that you currently should not try to repair electronic stuff as you are currently missing the basics unfortunately.

Comment: [Photos of the PCBs](https://imgur.com/a/7FBVizU)

Comment: everett1992, the components reside on the back side. You would need to unscrew the PCB to take such a picture.

Comment: The album includes pictures of the front side.